# Add attribute to a tag if title matches

Tags: jquery

I want to add an attribute "target=_blank" if the `<a>` has title "extension".

```
<ul id="mob-right-menu">
<li class="menu-item><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li class="menu-item><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="menu-item><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li class="menu-item><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li class="menu-item><a href="#">Newsroom</a></li>
<li class="menu-item><a href="http://google.com" title="extension">Extensions</a></li>    
</ul>
```

I have added a last menu recently, I want to add an attribute as below.

```
<li class="menu-item><a href="http://google.com" title="extension" target="_blank">Extensions</a></li>
```

as it is an external url and I want it to be opened in a new tab, can anyone please help me out.

Comment: `$('#mob-right-menu a[title="extension"]').attr('target', '_blank')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Loop through each `a` tag.
- Check its `title` attribute value
- Change/add its `target` attribute value

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('title')=="extension")
    $(this).attr('target','_blank');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mob-right-menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Newsroom</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://google.com" title="extension">Extensions</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#mob-right-menu a[title="extension"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

When your file is load it will add target into your hyperlink.